# Why do planes use wire HF antennas instead of smaller ones used by airliners?

Tags: aircraft-design, antenna

why do some planes have wire Hf antennas if smaller hub antennas are more aerodynamic? like on the Boeing 787? Why do some modern aircraft like the c130 still have them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a point of note, the versions of the C-130 which use wire antennas are far from modern! The J model which is the most modern (‘90s) doesn’t use a wire HF antenna.

Answer (score 3):

The antenna length is purely a function of frequency.  In other words it is a function of the radio systems that were prevalent when the aircraft entered service, and not specifically the age of the aircraft and radios.

The wavelength of a radio signal at 4 MHz is about 80 meters or 250 feet long.  The wavelength of a radio signal in the typical VHF NAV/COM band is around 2 meters, or 6 feet.

There are certain lengths of antennas that are more efficient than others, and 1/4 wavelength and 5/8 wavelength antennae offer excellent tradeoffs between length and signal strength.  A typical NAV/COM "whip" on a light aircraft will often be about 18" long for exactly that reason.

More and more navigation is being done using much higher frequencies, especially as digital radio component costs have shrunk drastically.  Many of the services on your image are UHF or even above where the wavelengths involved can be 70cm, and GPS is around 20cm.  You're talking about quarter-wavelength antennae, or even phased arrays, that are a few inches across.

Today, ADF is the only long-wavelength radio service still sometimes used in instrument navigation, so you do sometimes see GA aircraft with the tail wire antennae for ADF sense.  But that is becoming increasingly rare as GPS becomes ubiquitous.

A notable place where you will see long wire antennae in active use?  Military, cargo, bush operations, etc.  And for two reasons:

- **Geographic:**  There are still many places where you don't want to rely solely on GPS (more accurately GNSS) as your sole means of navigation, but there are no other sources of VHF or UHF navaids.  And so the backup to the GPS may very well be a HF beacon, an AM radio station, or even a regional shortwave broadcaster.
- **Communications:**  There are other use cases that cannot be met by GPS.  In many military and remote area operations, that long wire is also a communication antenna on which HF comm signals are transmitted and received.  In military or remote operations, I have three choices:  Relatively short-range, line-of-sight VHF/UHF comms, satellite comms, and HF/LF comms capable of propagation over the horizon.  I'm not sure how common it is, but even recently the use of HF comms were common for oceanic airline flights,

Comment: I think the question is more interested in HF comm antennas -- some modern aircraft still have long-wire HF antennas, and others have the in-the-tail HF antennas.  Why are both still around, with one type used "here" but the other type used "there"?

Comment: That is the question. But I did like the answer given above.

Comment: @Boeing787 I may edit my answer to clarify then...

Comment: One thought I had was that you can’t hide an antenna in a metal fuselage but you could in a composite one.  Don’t know if that has any real bearing in it though

Comment: @Max so would you say that smaller HF antennas on airliners is not as powerful as wire antennas?

Comment: @Boeing787 It’s not quite that simple, as is so often the case.  Running 100 watts of transmit power into an antenna that has 3db of gain is the same effective radiated power as running 50 watts into an antenna with 6dB of gain.  The engineering objective is to provide reliable transmit and receive over the distance required, and as long as that objective is met, more is not necessarily any better.  And advances in digital signal processing have steadily shrunk the importance of antenna size over the last 30 or so years.

Comment: Replying to: I'm not sure how common it is, but even recently the use of HF comms were common for oceanic airline flights,
-----------------------
Yes it is common even mandatory (due to vast deserts) by some african countries aviation authorities to be at least one HF comm Tx/Rx fitted to the aircraft to be registered there.

Comment: @Max because I've seen pictures of Cessna citations and Pilatus pc12's with wire antennas.